# All possible inverse laplace transform of $ (s+1)^2/(s^2+2s+1)$

Tags: laplace-transform

Well this was the question given in our previous week's test:
Find all possible Inverse Laplace Tranforms of $(s+1)^2/(s^2+2s+1)$ .

I just expanded the numerator and so the function reduced to 1.And the inverse Laplace transform of $1$ is $\delta(t)$.

But I am starting to doubt if what I have done is correct or not. Because the given function is undefined at $s= -1$.

Can anyone help me with this question.

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: I may be a goof, but aren't both Numerator and Denominator divisible by $s+1$?

Comment: Well thats my whole doubt, we dont no wat the value of the function at s=-1

Comment: The expression does not exist at s=-1, but as a limit it does. It is then 1. You would be taking the inverse laplace of 1 with keeping in mind that s=-1 is not to be considered

Comment: Thanx buddy sounds reasonable